# preg_match is not working as expected

Tags: php, preg-match, cyrillic

I'm using such pattern to find cyrillic symbols in my text, but it is returning true on unicode currency symbols "₴" (ukrainian hryvnya) and "€" (euro)

```
$pat = '/.*[А-Яа-яёЁ].*/';
$res = preg_match($pat, $str);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Not knowing too much about the Unicode order myself, is it possible that unicode currency symbol values exist between А-Я or between а-я? It seems unlikely, but worth a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make your pattern unicode-aware with `/u` modifier:

```
$pat = '/.*[А-Яа-яёЁ].*/u';
$res = preg_match($pat, $str);
```

Quoting [**the doc**](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> u (PCRE_UTF8)
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/225671). BTW, if you only check whether or not cyrillic letters are present in the string without doing anything on the match (and with the given code you do), you can drop `.*` parts from your pattern.